# paste0 is putting " in wrong place

Tags: r

I am creating columns of variables.

```
myVars=paste0("var",rep(1:5))
myVars
paste0(myVars,"=rnorm(5)")
```

output:

```
"var1=rnorm(5)" "var2=rnorm(5)" "var3=rnorm(5)" "var4=rnorm(5)"
"var5=rnorm(5)"
```

note the second quote should be after var1 as seen below.
I also want to paste in the comma seen in wanted output.
That should require something like paste0(A,B,C)

Want:

```
"var1"=rnorm(5), "var2"=rnorm(5), "var3"=rnorm(5), "var4"=rnorm(5),
"var5"=rnorm(5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need to have double quotes around 'myVars', use `dQuote` with `q = FALSE` to avoid having the fancyquotes

```
out <- paste0(dQuote(myVars, q = FALSE), "=rnorm(5)")
cat(out, '\n')
#"var1"=rnorm(5) "var2"=rnorm(5) "var3"=rnorm(5) "var4"=rnorm(5) "var5"=rnorm(5)
```

if it should be a single string

```
out1 <- paste(dQuote(myVars, q = FALSE), "=rnorm(5)", sep="", collapse=", ")
cat(out1, '\n')
#"var1"=rnorm(5), "var2"=rnorm(5), "var3"=rnorm(5), "var4"=rnorm(5), "var5"=rnorm(5)
```

Comment: The explanation helps. I am trying to improve. Thanks. MM